# I add data from 4 requests to 3 requests, the operation is performed without errors, but the data does not appear, but only disappears

Tags: sql

I add data from 4 requests to 3 requests, the operation is performed without errors, but the data does not appear, but only disappears. I can't solve it for 2 hours already

[enter image description here](https://i.s[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owGAd.png)tack.imgur.com/FnuJr.png)

I add data from 4 requests to 3 requests, the operation is performed without errors, but the data does not appear, but only disappears. I can't solve it for 2 hours already[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMwUV.png)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884)

Comment: I'd suggest using column and table names in English, since this is an English language site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.